# Download excel file asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, excel, ajax, webforms, webmethod

I want to generate excel file in server and let the client save /download it.
the thing is that to generate the excel i am calling db and make actions that took 1 minute. 
i want to show the user loading icon untill the popup jumps and ask user where to save the file.

i think there are 3 ways?
1. webmethod and ajax? (to hide and show the loading)
2. ashx and ajax?
3. onserverclick with registerclientblock script?

anyway i dont know how to use any of these ways.

please help me :)

```
  FileInfo fileName = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\liron\Desktop\123.xlsx");
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName.Name);
  Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
  Response.Charset = "";
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileName.Length.ToString());
  Response.TransmitFile(fileName.FullName);
  Response.End();
```

Comment: you can show a loading icon on a normal Postback too, if you dont want to implement one of your three methods.

Comment: how?...........

Comment: how do you start your download? click on a submit-button-server-control? are you using update-panels? can you provide more sample code?